# select2 or chosen: how to extend funcationality

Tags: jquery-select2, multi-select, jquery-chosen, bootstrap-multiselect

[select2](https://select2.org/) or [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) or [bootstrap-multiselect](http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options)

I am looking for a way to show the options in a multi select, just like plain simple "multiple" option does to the regular select control.

It saves a click! it saves a click (the need to open the dropdown to see the options), when you have to select multiple options. I am not able to find anywhere any documentation regarding that.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are asking not about "list as it is in HTML" (note: there are no one unified solution - see multiselect on mobile devices, they are not the same as on desktop) but about list that is in popup which is opened by click ant that is NOT CLOSED till you could finish all your selections? One click is requried, but not "click to open, click to select, click to open, click to select ..."?

Chosen can't do this (chosen closes popup after selection).

bootstrap-multiselect can, but its list is not very friendly: 1) it can change its location (jump up and down) under the mouse, and 2) is usually "too wide" - checkboxes are too far from text (text aligned left, checkbox aligned right).

You can try my component: https://github.com/DashboardCode/BsMultiSelect

Here dropdown menu is not closed till you had finished all your selections, and it can't look "too wide" if you have "wider" length of your input control.